# Can I force Google geocoding API to include the postcode on geocoding request?

Tags: google-maps, google-api, geocoding, google-geocoding-api

I am using [Google Geocoding API](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/geocoding/intro) to get `lat`, `lng`, `country` and `postal_code` from any address string.

In certain situations I noticed a problem where in my opinion the API is wasteful with requests. Is there a way to work around it or even an intended solution that I don't see?

- Situation: The address string contains only town name plus country name. e.g. `New York, USA`
- Problem: even though the address string is correctly geocoded (i.e. I get `lat`, `lng`) somewhere in the city center, I don't get a `postal_code`. I can now reverse geocode using `lat`, `lng` and get my `postal_code` that way, but now **I have to make two requests**
- can I force the API somehow to include `postal_code` right away?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In example that you provided, request `https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=New%20York%2C%20USA&key=YOUR_API_KEY` returns a feature of type locality (place ID ChIJOwg_06VPwokRYv534QaPC8g).

Note that this feature refers to entire city, not to the position of the center of the city.

https://google-developers.appspot.com/maps/documentation/utils/geocoder/#q%3DNew%2520York%252C%2520USA

As locality is not a single point (it has a polygon shape) and the feature of locality overlaps many features of postal codes, Google doesn't return any value for postal code due to ambiguity. Unfortunately, you cannot change this behavior. The only workaround as you mentioned is reverse geocode a postal code of the central point.

I hope my answer clears up your doubt.